# Getting the Server in Global.asax in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When our **ASP.NET MVC 4** app starts, we need to set a property on a **Log4Net Appender** which depends on what the site is.

Is there a way to get the 'http://www.site.com' part some time in the sites initial load, perhaps in Global.asax?

**Overview:**
If the server is www.site2.com then set the Appender.SomeValue = "555"
If the server is www.site.com then set the Appender.SomeValue = "123"

Because many sites will point to the same code base we don't know what we need to set Appender.SomeValue to until it runs.

Comment: Care to explain more what you're trying to do? There might be a different way to configure log4net that gives you the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-application start is more limited as it is run before the application is started, more for initializing di containers. To be safe I would put the code in a new static method defined in global.asax.cs that is called by application_start method at this point access to HttpContext.Current.request.Url should be safe

Answer (score 1):

I think methods in Global.asax would run, only in response to a request. And almost everywhere inside the ASP.NET, you have access to `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`.

Also there is a method that runs way before `Application_Start`, and that is a method decorated with [`PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

One approach is to use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to get access to the current website, it's bindings and thus the site address.